# How can I stop the countdown until the localStorage expires?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

The following script makes a countdown until it reaches the set number (in this case 76), after which it starts again the countdown and so on. Updating the page the countdown does not reset until the localStorage expires.

I want that when the countdown reaches 76 it stops and doesn't start counting again. This until the localStorage expires. Please how can I do this?

```html
<div id="divCounter"></div>
```

```
var min = 80;
var max = 85;
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (+max - +min)) + +min;

if (localStorage.getItem("counter")) {
  if (localStorage.getItem("counter") >= 1000000000) { // Duration of localStorage
    var value = random;
  } else {
    var value = localStorage.getItem("counter");
  }
} else {
  var value = random;
}

document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = value;

var counter = function () {
  if (value <= 76) { // End count down. <= or >=
    localStorage.setItem("counter", random);
    value = random;
  } else {
    value = parseInt(value) - 1; // + 1 or - 1
    localStorage.setItem("counter", value);
  }

  document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = value;
};

var interval = setInterval(function () {
  counter();
}, 1000); // speed count
```

Comment: Didn't get your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with this code, but given how it is here, you need to call clearInterval(interval) when value <= 76 to stop localStorage from changing again at that point.

Comment: Please what problems are there with this script? Thanks!

Comment: I can't understand what are you actually trying to do here by looking at the code. I was trying to refactor it myself and am finding it hard to reason about.

Comment: Why do you need localStorage at all here?

Comment: This is my best guess at your intention here:

Comment: Avoid setInterval() where possible, use setTimeout() and reschedule after completion. What happens on slow machines where localstorage update takes longer than the interval?

Comment: I need a countdown that starts at "XX" and ends at "XX". Use localStorage to avoid "reset" the count when refreshing the page. At the end of the localStorage the countdown starts again counting.

Comment: "At the end of the localStorage the countdown starts again counting." from the original random value or does it start counting up again?

Comment: from the original random value

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess at your intention:

```
// If there's a count in localStorage but it is expired then
//      set value to a random between 80 and 85
// else
//      set value to the count in localStorage

// Display the count in a div and decrease it by 1 every second. 
// If the count falls below 76 then 
//      stop counting down and
//      reset the localStorage counter to the random value

        const min = 80;
        const max = 85;
        const stopValue = 76;
        const duration = 1000000000;
        const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

        const counter = () => {
            const lsCounter = localStorage.getItem('counter');

            let retval;

            if(lsCounter && lsCounter <= duration){
                retval = lsCounter - 1;
                if(lsCounter <= stopValue){
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    retval = rnd;
                }
            }else{
                retval = rnd;
            }
            localStorage.setItem('counter', retval);
            document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = retval;
        }
        let interval = setInterval(function () {
            counter();
        }, 1000);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, right. When the count reaches 76 it stops and starts again with the random numbers only at the end of the localStorage (in this case 1000000000 second)

Comment: "starts again with the random numbers": a new random number or the same as before? In your case, it will always be the same random until the page is refreshed.

Comment: how are you tracking expiration? is that another counter in local storage?

Comment: I'm just curious b/c I was going to give you another version.

Comment: I have only set 1000000000 seconds as the duration of the localStorage

Comment: How did you do that? 1000000000 seconds since when? How do you know when they have elapsed?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know  :(

Comment: That's ok. I just edited my other answer with a version that works without the expiration. The main idea was to make it easier to understand. I'm glad I could help. Best of luck to you.